# What is wrong with my 'counterexample' to the Aanderaa-Rosenberg conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory

In a Topological Approach to Evasiveness by Jeff Kahn, Michael Saks and Dean Sturtevant, they propose the following game:

> Suppose we are given a digraph $D$ on $v$ vertices via an oracle which answers questions of the form "is $(x, y)$ an edge of $D$? (We may think of this oracle as the adjacency matrix of $D$.) Our objective is to determine whether $D$ has a given (isomorphism invariant) property $P$ while minimizing the worst case number of queries to the oracle.

Later he poses this question:

> **Aanderaa-Rosenberg Conjecture** There is a constant $\epsilon > 0$ such that any non-trivial monotone digraph property on $v$ vertices has complexity at least $\epsilon v^2$.
>
> A *non-trivial* property is one which holds for some, but not all digraphs. A *monotone* property is one which is not destroyed by the addition of edges.

Now my question is consider the following property:

> For some graph $G$, does $G$ have at least $2$ vertices?

1. This property is non-trivial: The graph with just a point has $1$ vertex.
2. This property is monotone: The number of vertices don't depend on the number of edges.

I don't see why this has a complexity of $\epsilon v^2$. One should only need to check if there exists two rows in the adjacency matrix and we are done. What obvious thing am I overlooking?

Comment: For any fixed $v$, the property is trivial.

Comment: Yes, triviality is not about all $v$ at the same time, but per $v$, I believe.

Comment: @Misha: Oh thanks that makes sense. I knew there was something simple I was missing.

Comment: You have not defined the "complexity" of a digraph property. Is it related somehow to the number of oracle queries mentioned in the first block quote?

Comment: @bof: Yes. The idea is I would have to query on the order $v^2$ times. Where $v$ is the number of vertices.